# AngularJS update model from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope, directive

I need to update my model from my directive. Here is my directive, controller function, and my view.

```
angular.module('madReportingToolApp')
.directive('supplyDemandChart', function ($window) {
    return {
        template: '',
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 75, left: 50},
                width = element.width() - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            if (scope.currentSelection.children.length > 1) {
                width = (element.width() / 2) - margin.left - margin.right;
            }

            var data = scope.currentSelection,
                selector = '#' + element[0].id;
            data.children.forEach(function (child) {

                var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

                var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

                var y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0]);

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x0)
                    .orient("bottom");

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left");

                var graphContainer = d3.select(selector).append("div")
                    .attr("class", "graph-container");

                graphContainer.append("h2")
                    .text(child.name)
                    .attr("class", "graph-header")
                    .style("margin", "50%");

                var svg = graphContainer.append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "parentGraphic")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                    .on("click", function(){
                        debugger
                        scope.setCurrentSelection(child);


                    });

                x0.domain(data.weekData.map(function (d) {
                    return d.week;
                }));

                x1.domain(['Supply', 'Demand']).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

                y.domain([0, d3.max(data.weekData, function (d) {
                    return d.supply > d.demand ? d.supply : d.demand;
                })]);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                    .attr("dy", ".15em")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "rotate(-65)"
                    });

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis)
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".5em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Supply");

                var inner = svg.selectAll(".inner")
                    .data(data.weekData)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "g graphBar")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + x0(d.week) + ",0)";
                    });

                inner.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(function (d) {
                        return d.innerData
                    })
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", function (d) {
                        return 'bar ' + d.name
                    })
                    .attr("x", function (d) {
                        return x1(d.name);
                    })
                    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return y(d.value);
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) {
                        return height - y(d.value);
                    });

            });
        }
    };
});
```

My Controller function:

```
$scope.setCurrentSelection = function(objName){
        var children = $scope.currentSelection.children;

        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
            if(children[i].name === objName){
                $scope.currentSelection = children[i];
            }
        }
        $scope.displayProductGraph = false;
        $scope.displayGeoGraph = true;
    }
```

My view:

`<section class="col-xs-12" ng-if="isGraphDisplayed" style="padding: 0px">
    <div ng-if="$parent.displayProductGraph">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
        <div id="mad-product-graph" class="col-xs-12" supply-demand-chart></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="$parent.displayGeoGraph">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
        <div id="mad-geo-graph" class="col-xs-12" supply-demand-chart></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="$parent.displayLv1CustomerGraph">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
        <div id="mad-lv1-customer-graph" class="col-xs-12" supply-demand-chart></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="$parent.displayLv3CustomerGraph">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
        <div id="mad-lv3-customer-graph" class="col-xs-12" supply-demand-chart></div>
    </div>
</section>`

Basically what I need to have happen, is when the user clicks on the svg image, it will hide the current image shown and display a new image. This is done by calling the same directive but with slightly different parameters.

My scope object in the directive has access to the necessary fields (currentSelection, displayProductGraph, etc). However, if I update the model either by calling a function to update it (see Controller function) or if I update the model directly by setting

```
scope.displayGeoGraph = true
scope.displayProductGraph = false
```

Nothing happens in my view. E.G the ng-if doesn't recognize that those boolean values have changed.

Why does my scope in my directive not seem to update my controller's scope, even though they're technically the same scope?

Thanks in advance